# A special case of Catalan's conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory

Solve equation
$$ y^p -  (2^p-1)^x = 1 $$
where $x,y>0 \in \mathbb{Z}$, $p \in \mathbb{P}$. 
Is there a elementary method to do it?
Thanks. =)

Comment: In a way: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture as the only possible solution is 9 - 8 = 1.

Comment: @Will, and thus there are no solutions. Right?

Comment: Dear Will, but it's toooo hard to show that Catalan's conjecture is right. Can we find a easier proof? Dear Johan, there are only a solution $(x,y)=(1,2)$.

Comment: That pair doesn't give a solution of the equation, dear Lwins.


Comment: @Lwins To specify a solution, you should also give a value for $p$. And I assume that $\mathbb{P}$ denotes the set of primes. If not, it would be *very* helpful to tell us what $\mathbb{P}$ is.

Like J. H. S. pointed out, $(x,y) = (1,2)$ does not give a solution, since $2^{p} - 1 - 2^{p} = -1 \ne 1$.

Furthermore, even though it is hard to prove Catalan's conjecture, others have done this for you. So please accept that fact, and conclude that there are no solutions to your equation (under the constraints that you posed on $x$, $y$, and $p$).

Comment: Dear Johan, sorry, I've modified it. Now $(1,2)$ is a solution.

Comment: Ok, now I object to the title, because Catalan's conjecture requires $x > 1$. However, if $x = 1$, it is easy to show that $(x,y) = (1,2)$ is the only solution, and is a solution for every $p \in \mathbb{P}$. For $x > 1$, the result follows from Catalan's conjecture (i.e., there are no solutions to your equation).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose the equation is
$$y^p-z^r=1,$$
with $p,r$ odd primes. The classical approach to Catalan's conjecture was to consider two cases (similar to Fermat's last theorem) which go as follows:

First you rearrange the equation as
$$(y-1)\left(\frac{y^p-1}{y-1}\right)=z^r$$
and then you consider the $\gcd$ of the factors on the left, it can only take the values $1$ or $p$. The first case $\gcd(y-1,\frac{y^p-1}{y-1})=1$ was shown to have no solutions by Cassels

> J.W.S. Cassels, On the equation $a^x-b^y=1$, II, Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 56 (1960), 97-103

with another proof given by S. Hyyro later. Cassels' proof uses elementary techniques. The punchline is that the second (hard) case is when $r| y$ and $p|z$.

Coming back to your equation we see that $2^p-1\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, so we are in the first case, and you do not need the full strength of Mihăilescu's proof.

Comment: This is of course assuming that $x$ has a prime divisor, otherwise you have the trivial solution $(x,y)=(1,2)$ mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I do not see why $2^{p} - 1 \cong 1 \pmod{p}$ forces us into the first case. Maybe I am confused by the fact that your $x$ is not the same $x$ as that of the questioner.

Comment: I'm grateful for your patient. Very nice answer, I think. Thanks. =)

Comment: Johan, I renamed the variables. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: To Johan, obviously $(y-1,\frac{y^p-1}{y-1})=(y-1,p) \mid p$. So show that $p \nmid y-1$ is enough. It's trivial because $y \equiv 1 \pmod p \implies (2^p-1) \equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Comment: Of course! Sorry for my brainfart, and thanks for clearing things up!

Answer (score 0):

I think this gives a nice elementary solution, too.
See this: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=505773